# Use variable for default value if imported role failed

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible role that reads data from a DB. That data might not exist in which case it fails. I cannot change this role. Currently I'm using this role like:

```
- name: Import role and read values
  import_role:
      name: shared_role
  register: value
```

This works well when the data in the DB exists and the role doesn't fail. However when that data is missing it's causing more problems. So in case of an error I want to ignore that error and use a default  value.

```
- import_role:
      name: shared_role
  register: value
  ignore_errors: true
- set_fact:
    value: "{{ value | default({{ default_var }}) }}"
```

where default_var is defined in group_vars. Now this doesn't work obviously and I'm kind of stuck. How could I use a variable as a default value foor another variable registered in a role that might have failed... if that makes sense.

Comment: I suspect that the `value` variable is actually a structure with a lot of stuff in it.  Dump that out in a `debug` and see whether what you need is in there.

Comment: No actually that's a simple value or None. I could reduce the question to :How to use variables in default filter, like: default({{ some_var }}) or default(lookup(vars, 'some_var'))

Comment: Check registered value of `value` and Use `when` clause during `set_fact` to set appropriate value.

Comment: you dont need `{{ }}` around `default_var` inside `value`

Comment: try `value: "{{ value | default( default_var ) }}" ` this worked for me when I declared `vars` variable and assign that variable in `default() `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`default` will by default (sorry for this redundancy but I don't know how to write it better) replace values for **undefined variables only**. A variable defined as `None` **is** defined.

Fortunately, there is a second parameter that can be used to replace also "empty" vars (i.e. `None`, or empty string). See [Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#providing-default-values) for this

Moreover, you cannot use jinja2 expansion while inside a jinja2 expansion already. Check the [jinja2 documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/) to learn more.

So you should achieve your requirement with the following expression (if all you described about your data is correct):

```yaml
- set_fact:
    value: "{{ value | default(default_var, true) }}"
```

You should not have problems with [variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence) here: `set_fact` and `register` are on the same level so the latest assignment should win. But for clarity and security, I would rename that var so you are sure you never get into trouble:

```yaml
- import_role:
    name: shared_role
  register: role_value
  ignore_errors: true
- set_fact:
    value: "{{ role_value | default(default_var, true) }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple syntax error. You can not use the `{{}}` in a filter.
The correct syntax is

```yaml
- set_fact:
    value: "{{ value | default(default_var) }}"
```

EDIT:
If your value is `"None"` and you want to replace that, you can use something like this:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    value: "{%- if not value is defined or value == 'None' -%}{{ default_var }}{%- else -%}{{ value }}{%- endif -%}"
```

Take note of the use of `{{}}` here.

Comment: This will only use `default_var` if `value` is undefined. Since it is a registered var, it is defined: OP shared in a comment that the value is `None` when the role fails. In this case, the value will not be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my `group_vars/all.yml` file. I am using `food` that is defined here to set in my play. you can see the value `6` in output.

```
 logs: /var/log/messages
   foo: 6
```

and here is my play-book

```
   ---
   - name: assign a variable value in default state
     hosts: localhost
     tasks:
     - name: set fact and then print
       set_fact:
         new_var: "{{ doodle | default( foo ) }}"
     - name: debug
       debug: msg="{{ new_var }}"
```

and here is the output

```
PLAY [assign a variable value in default state] ********************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set fact and then print] *************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
   

>  "msg": "6"

}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: This works because `doodle` is undefined. OP shared in comments that his `value` is `None` (i.e. defined). Meanwhile I am not the downvoter and I don't think this 'mistake' is worth one ;)

Comment: thanks for clarifying that. I did suggest my solution in the comment first. I thought I would just demonstrate with sample code. Thanks for answering a tonne of questions here. I learn a lot from your insights. I am a wanna be Ansible coder :)

Comment: Not the downvoter either, but a first quick read of your answer made it look like unrelated to the question. I would say the reason is because you changed too much of the OP's playbook. You could have kept the OP variables names and still demonstrate your point. Just my 2 cents.